# How to get the downloaded data of a failed NSURLSessionDownloadTask?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, resume, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I would like to know if  I can retrieve the parial downloadede data of a failed NSURLSessionDownloadTask.

My use case is:

1. I launch a download of a 1024MB file
2. 512MB are downloaded
3. The download fails because of network interruption
4. When the download fails, the  delagte's -(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
   task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
   is called. But the error object does not contain the path to the
   512MB file of downloaded data.

My question is: is it possible to retrieve the downloaded 512MB using the **NSURLSession** APIs with a **background session**?

Thanks,

Comment: Doesn't look like it.  You should probably write your own version; can't be hard.

Comment: What do you mean by write your own version? Should I make a subclass of NSURLSessionDownloadTask?

Comment: No, use iOS framework network classes, or AFNetworking etc., and create a class that does the downloading for you.

Comment: But I need to take advantage of the NSURLSession background mode in order to keep the downloads running when the app is in the background. As far as I know, AFNetworking do not support a background nsurlsession

Comment: Ah OK; you cannot write your own then.

Comment: In conclusion, the answer of my post is no I cannot. Thanks for the replies ^^.

Answer (score 2):

Apple Documentation States:

If a transfer fails, the session object provides an NSError object either to your delegate or to the task’s completion handler. In that object, the NSURLSessionDownloadTaskResumeData key in the userInfo dictionary contains a resumeData object.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/downloadTaskWithResumeData:

Answer (score 1):

Further to the answer already posted (and expanding on it), you can access the data already downloaded via the `error` object itself, as follows:

```
NSData* resume_data = error.userInfo[NSURLSessionDownloadTaskResumeData];
```